# Do I have the chain rule right?

Tags: chain-rule

I was revising [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) and I made up a problem to write down in my notes that uses it at least two times. Here it is, if a function $\zeta(x) = (z(x))^2$ where $z(x) = x + f(x), f(x) = \ln(g(x))$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2$ then $\zeta'$ or $\frac{d\zeta}{dx}$ is defined as,
\begin{align*}
  \zeta'(x) & = \frac{d\zeta}{dz}\times \frac{dz}{df}\times \frac{df}{dg} \times \frac{dg}{dx}\\
  \zeta'(x) & = 2(z(x))z'(x) \\
            & = 2(z(x))(1 + f'(x)) \\
            & = 2(z(x))(1 + (\ln(g(x)))') \\
            & = 2(z(x))\Big(1 + \Big(\frac{1}{g(x)}\Big)g'(x)\Big) \\
            & = 2(z(x))\Big(1 + \Big(\frac{1}{g(x)}\Big)x\Big) \\
\end{align*}

Did I get it right?

Comment: Be confident in your work. And yes, it is correct.

Comment: Correct from the 2nd line to the end. You did not use the 1st line, & it's good that you didn't, else you would be stuck at the term $\frac {dz}{df}=\frac {d(x+f(x))}{df(x)}=??$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet read the comments under Matheus's answer. That is exactly what got me. Could you please explain perhaps in an answer how can one correctly write the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a little more confidence! Your work is completely correct.

About writing it in Leibniz notation: we have $\zeta(x) = \varphi(y)$, where $\varphi$ is defined by $x \mapsto x^2$ and $h$ by $y \mapsto h(y) = y + f(y)$. Therefore: $$ \begin{aligned} \frac{\mathrm{d}\zeta}{\mathrm{d}x} &= \frac{\mathrm{d} \varphi}{\mathrm{d}y} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \\ &= \frac{\mathrm{d} \varphi}{\mathrm{d}y} \left(1  + \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}  \right) \end{aligned}$$

And from here on you can use the definitions of $f$ and $g$ to expand the last equality in terms of $f$ and $g$, but I'd rather leave it at just the first one.

Comment: Could you help me write it in Leibniz form? I know it'll be something like $\frac{d\zeta}{?} \frac{df}{dg} \frac{dg}{dx}$. But what will go in place of the question mark?

Comment: $\operatorname{d}f$? So it cancels out while multiplication

Comment: @scribe I've added an edit that I think will help

Comment: Okay I see, I edited my post. Though I have managed to confuse myself a little about $\frac{dz}{df}$. $\frac{dz}{df}$ says that we are taking the derivative of $z$ with respect to $f$. Since it is with respect to $f$, should we not treat the $x$ in $z(x) = x +f(x)$ as constant, yielding $\frac{dz}{df} = f'(x)$? I know this is wrong and my instinct the first time was right. But now I can't pin point to why $\frac{dz}{df} = f'(x)$ is incorrect.

Comment: @scribe It's incorrect because $z$ is not to be treated as a function of $f$, rather of $x$. It doesn't depend on $f$, because $f$ is a fixed function, unlike $x$, which takes values on the whole domain of $z$.

Comment: I suppose then I am confused about how could we write a function in the denominator of Leibniz notation because if I understand correctly in $df / dx$,  $f$ is always a function and $x$ a variable in it (hence differentiating $f$ with respect to $x$). Could you have a look at the first line of my edited equations and see if it is still correct as some pointed out that it is not.